# read and pipe mail content to bash script using mail /var/spool/mail

Tags: bash, email

I'm writing a sript to read mail content and piping to a bunch of regexes in order to get some important status info.

my script is:

```
for ((i=START; counter<=${number_of_mails}; counter++)) 
do
mail_content=""$(echo $counter | mail -f /var/spool/mail/user)

# ....... processing mail content $counter
# doing some stuff

done
```

The problem is that mailcontent is "raw" mail content like this:

```
e: 12px; margin: 0px auto; font-family: Arial, sans-seri=
f !important;"></a> &nbsp; <a href=3D"http://post.spmailtechnolo.com/f/a/mg=
ds0nF2qSAHBvHw5u7zUw~~/AAEd7AA~/RgRbciuJP0EIACzE6PGZ5slXA3NwY1gEAAAAAFkHZGV=
TI5OTEmeHRvcj1FUFItMzEyOTcyNjEyLVtjb3VudGVyX29mZmVyX2NvbnRhY3RfMjAxNzA4MTRd=
LTIwMTcwODE0LVtpbnN0YWdyYW1dLVtdLVtdLVtdJnVybD1odHRwOi8vaW5zdGFncmFtLmNvbS9=
pZGVhbGlzdGFjb21HAnt9" style=3D"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: rgb(102, =
102, 102); font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;"><im=
g src=3D"https://www.instagram.com/static/email/img/badge_instagram.png" al=
t=3D"instagram" style=3D"padding: 0px; border: none; font-size: 12px; margi=
n: 0px auto; font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;"></a> </td></tr></t=
body> </table> </td></tr></tbody> </table> </td></tr></tbody> </table> </td=
></tr><tr id=3D"bottom" style=3D"margin: 0px; padding: 5px 0px 0px; font-fa=
mily: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px;"> <td style=3D"margin: 0px; font-=
```

That's a pain to process with regexes. I just need to get some info from mail message.
How can I read the mail message not struggling with this stuff?. Just Reading text, not all HTML and such

Comment: It's unclear from the text you have given, the exact data you would like to extract.

Comment: The content in plain text. Not the gibberish